# i did not understand the error. Can anyone solve this?

Tags: grails

When I logged in to my application this error comes up.
 Can anybody explain this??

**Error :-**

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI/BookForAsia/Classorg.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException
Message securityUser is not mapped
Around line 101 of grails-app\realms\org\ng\securityDbRealm.groovy

101: def results = SecurityUser.executeQuery("select distinct p from securityUser 
 as user join user.permissions as p where user.username = '$principal'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have to capitalize `securityUser` in your HQL query so it becomes `SecurityUser`?